# How to interpret :: in scala

Tags: scala, covariant

I write the following code:

```
class Animal
class Bird extends Animal
val animalList = List(new Animal, new Animal)
new Bird :: animalList
```

The implementation of the `::` method looks like this:

```
def ::[B >: A] (x: B): List[B] =
  new scala.collection.immutable.::(x, this)
```

I expected the return type to be `List[Bird]`. Why is it `List[Animal]`?

Comment: `B >: A` -> B is a superclass of A. The most strict superclass of `Animal` and `Bird` is `Animal`. Bird is inferred to be an Animal because A is `Animal` and B is a superclass of A, so in this case `B` = `A` = Animal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dotless infix notation of

```
new Bird :: animalList
```

desugars to

```
animalList.::(new Bird)
```

because method names ending with `:` are invoked on the object on the right-hand side of the expression.

If we explicitly specify `Bird` as the type argument...

```
animalList.::[Bird](new Bird)
```

... then the compiler tells us why that doesn't work:

> error: type arguments `[Bird]` do not conform to method `::`'s type parameter bounds `[B >: Animal]`

There are two constraints on the type of `B`:

- `B >: A` in the method signature means `B` has to be a supertype of the list's type (`A`, which here is `Animal`).
- The value argument (`new Bird`) has to be an instance of `B` (because method arguments are covariant).

The compiler chooses the most specific type that satisfies both of these constraints, which is `Animal`.

```
animalList.::[Animal](new Bird)
```

Comment: I don't think that it's true that "infix notation desugars to (...)". It desugars to `animalList.::(new Bird)` which is a method and can't be called as you presented it. `::(new Bird, animalList)` works (backticks not needed) because this calls apply method of `::` companion object. Although at the end of the day both call constructor of `::`.

Comment: @Łukasz Ah, thanks. I'm confusing Scala and Haskell. OOP is complicated ;) Fixed.